# NSPredicate and KVC collection operators

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, key-value-coding

Assume I have a `Core Data` class `Employer` with a 1-N relationship called employees.

This `employees` relationship maps to an `NSSet`. So far so good.

I want to create an `NSFetchRequest` of `Employer` with a predicate that requieres that `employees > 0`.

How can I create this predicate?

I tried `"employees.@count"`, but it seems to consider the whole thing a keyPath.

Comment: Show your actually code and describe the error you get

Answer (score 1):

You got the syntax backwards:

```
@count.employees
```